# What is `ezconf-agent` running on Ubuntu or how to discover exact where this module came from

Tags: process, cpu-load

There is `ezconf-agent` process taking 100% CPU (one core) all the time, running on Ubuntu server on Azure.

I can't find any resources in Internen for `ezconf-agent`.
How to discover exact where this module came from, where it is installed, used configs etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Well, particularly `ezconf-agent` was forgotten small tool by other developer.

To find out I used:

`top` to see PID process id

`sudo ls /proc/PID` would show everthing related to a process

and I took `/cwd` current working directory symlink
`sudo ls -l /proc/PID/cwd`

Then I could figure out from files in that directory.